# Extracting values from first array element with Jolt

Tags: json, jolt

I have the following JSON document:

```
{
    "pbid": 123,
    "pid": 0,
    "time": 1483551745000,
    "timestamp": "2017-01-04 17:42:25",
    "creationTime": 1483551789000,
    "creationTimestamp": "2017-01-04 17:43:09",
    "name": "myname",
    "triggeredComponents": [
        {
            "device": {
                "did": 20,
                "ip": "127.0.0.1",
                "firstSeen": 1427474095000,
                "lastSeen": 1483545006000,
                "typename": "dnsserver"
            },
            "time": 1483551789000
        }
    ]
}
```

Using Jolt I need to transform this into the following:

```
{
  "event_id" : 123,                ( pbid )
  "name" : "myname",               ( name )
  "did": "20",                     ( triggeredComponents[0].device.did )
  "first_seen": 1427474095000,     ( triggeredComponents[0].device.firstSeen )
  "last_seen": 1483545006000       ( triggeredComponents[0].device.lastSeen )
}
```

I'm fine with the basic shifts (`event_id` and `name`) but I can't figure out how to extract from the array.  This is my current attempt (I've tried a few other ways, too):

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "pbid": "event_id",
      "name": "name",
      "triggeredComponents" : {
        "*": {
          "did": "triggeredComponents[&1].device.did",
          "first_seen": "triggeredComponents[&1].device.firstSeen",
          "last_seen": "triggeredComponents[&1].device.lastSeen"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

After chasing with the vendor it appears that the `triggeredComponents` array will only contain one object, so I only need to look at the 0th element.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Spec

`[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "pbid": "event_id",
      "name": "name",
      "triggeredComponents": {
        "0": {
          "device": {
            "did": "did",
            "firstSeen": "first_seen",
            "lastSeen": "last_seen"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]`

You were missing the "device" between "triggeredComponents[0]" and "did".

Comment: Great, thanks, this works and now makes perfect sense. I'm a fan of Jolt but I can't seem to find any concrete documentation on the spec syntax, only examples...